# CTP 3.1 The "RunMdaTargetsInstall" task was not given a value for the required parameter "NpmInstallDir"

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I get the following error using Visual Studio 2013 CTP 3.1 when trying to build for android. any ideas?

```
The "RunMdaTargetsInstall" task was not given a value for the required parameter "NpmInstallDir"
```

Comment: This typically occurs if Node.js is not installed or installed incorrectly.  If you go to the command prompt, what happens if you type "npm config list"?